# How to organise advanced SQL in Rails app

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, conventions

What are the options for organising more advanced (and thus more complicated and bigger) SQL queries in a Rails app?

The purpose:

- keep SQL and related specs in conventional locations.
- extract the bigger, more reusable SQL into SQL functions, views, triggers (how to maintain the code of the funcs, views then? Migration isn't probably the best choice)
- reuse the snippets of SQL as part of AR, or as standalone.
- leverage most of the underlying database power (such as PostgreSQL CTE, FTS, extensions etc).
- keep the SQL manageable, maintainable.

Comment: I think it's a matter of preference, but I would probably implement more complex queries as views (the database kind of view, not the rails kind) with separate, read-only models. Then, those Models can declare `has_one(Foo)` to relate back to the table Model (this comment is confusing to write :D).

Comment: @Tim but you still do want to test those views and keep the code somewhere. Where do you do that?

Comment: Ahh, I see what you mean. I work mostly with Oracle DBs that will manage scripts on the database server. I guess you could just drop the sources into config/database/sql or something, since they are static. That's a little confusing though. Sorry, I guess I didn't quite grasp the question at first.

Comment: I'm not sure that all the SQL is static. Sometimes it uses some interpolation to adopt the script to a particular use-case instead of copying it all over again.

Answer (score 1):

I would consider packaging everything as a standalone gem/Rails Engine.

All the necessary custom SQL migrations (code to create views, functions, stored procedures, etc.) can be placed in, say, `/db/migrations/sql` and a custom Rake task can be written to run those migrations.

You can then write all sorts of tests/specs to exercise your database-specific views, functions, stored procs, etc.

This gem will have its own source repository and can have its own life/release cycle, all independent of your main app. It can conceivably be maintained by a pair consisting of a Ruby specialist (for the gem, specs, library) and a SQL specialist (obviously).

If this library/API is well-written, this nets you the added benefit of abstracting your main application from the low-level, database-specific code. That is, the application developers only have to worry about calling `Widget.complex_sql_query` and dealing with its return values without having to worry about maintaining it. Conversely, the database backend team needn't worry so much about how their code is used—so long as both teams agree on the API contract and all around test coverage is good.

This can be done with all the code integral to the main app, but having everything as a separate gem imposes a physical and psychological barrier that lets both teams focus on their respective areas of responsibility more easily.

Comment: That would definitely be a little too much.